# How does this recursion work? Can you explain how they got the output?

Tags: matlab, recursion

```
function fnum = fib(n)
if (n == 1) || (n == 2)
    fnum = 1;
else
    fnum = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
end
```

Can you explain how does each step outputs for the given input. For example inputting 7 gives me 13, 5 gives me 5, but I am not able to track how. I would highly appreciate your reply.

Comment: See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fPO8R79uV7A)

Comment: Try to use the MATLAB debugger to understand how the program works

Answer (score 2):

Recursion basically means that the function calls itself.

If we follow your function for `fib(3)`, you will see that what it does is call `fib(2)+fib(1)`. The values of these are defined, and are 1, so it will return 2.

If you call it with `fib(4)`, it will go and compute `fib(3)+fib(2)`. You already know what `fib(3)` does (see previous paragraph), and we already mentioned that `fib(2)` returns `1`.

If you call it with `fib(5)` it will go and compute `fib(4)+fib(3)`. See previous paragraph.

This is a very useful way of programming as it is a very simple function to compute something that is arguably more complicated. The most important thing is that you make sure that any recursive function has strong stopping criteria, else it can go forever!

Comment: It's also should be mentioned that recursion is slow in comparison to other methods, so when speed is important it worth look for other approaches. [For example in this case](http://www.matrixlab-examples.com/fibonacci-numbers.html)

Comment: Indeed, nice comment ;)

Comment: Not necessarily, smartly written code + smart compiler usually means tail call optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how Fibonacci series is defined? This function implements that recursively.

**Longer answer**

Fibonacci series is defined as

```
n(1) = 1
n(2) = 1
n(k+1) = n(k) + n(k-1)
```

So when you put 5 as argument, the expansion becomes

```
n(4+1) = n(4)+n(3)
       = n(3)+n(2)+n(2)+n(1)
       = n(2)+n(1)+1+1+1
       = 1+1+1+1+1
       = 5
```

A much easier back of envelop method is to start from first index and add last two terms to arrive at the next.

1, 1, 2 <- (1+1), 3 <- (2+1), 5 <- (3+2), ...

Comment: ok so lets say if i input 7 the else would produce fnum = (7-1) + (7-2) right? Can you please explain the steps if you don't mind

Comment: @JaZZyCooL Updated for n(5)

Answer (score 1):

The Fibonnacci series is defined as `f(1) = 1, f(2) = 1 and for all n > 2, f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)`

So when you call `fib(1)` it returns `1` same for `fib(2)`. But when you call `fib(3)` it returns `fib(3-1) + fib(3-2)` which is `fib(2) + fib(1) = 2`. And then when you call `fib(4)`it returns `fib(3) + fib(2) = (fib(2) + fib(1)) + fib(1) = 3`. And recursively the fibonnaci series is equal to `1, 1, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, ...`

For the code when n is different than 1 or 2 it call the function `fib` recursively. And when is equals to 1 or 2 it returns 1.